# Sucrose inhibits onion root mitosis? Why?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, homework, mitosis

I am doing an experiment about the growth of onion roots.

I put onion plants in different solutions of sucrose in water — 0.1M, 0.2M, 0.3M, 0.4M, 0.5M — with the root touching the water.

Measurements of root growth tells me that the presence of sucrose in the solution inhibits root growth.

Why does this happen? Does sucrose affect the root's mitosis? If so, how?

Comment: Have you used the same onion for all the experiments? If not, it could be due to the onions themselves rather than the enviroments they are in.

Comment: A formula does not identify a compound as many compounds have the same formula. This is an old question but I have edited it to replace the formula with the name of the compound I assume is being referred to.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr you are using a lot of sucrose. You would need to show us the data, but I'm not surprised if the plant gets confused / dies/ doesn't know what to do when you add so much.

An important aspect of experiments in biology is calibrating the treatment you're applying to the biological system. If you give a plant way more of an important signalling molecule than it would usually expect in nature, it may respond in a way that doesn't make any sense.

1M sucrose would be a 34% solution of sucrose (molar mass of sucrose is 342.3 g / M, in 1 L of solution).

If you look at [papers](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpls.2020.00409/full) or even at [hobbyist forums](https://www.ourfigs.com/forum/figs-home/417430-sugar-water-your-cuttings) where people add sucrose to stimulate root growth, they seem to usually be adding a 5% solution or less (50g / 1L ~ 0.16M), which is [described](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25412792/) as "high". So at the highest level you are adding more than 3X as much sucrose as people usually do.

I'd look at your data and try to understand whether the inhibition happens in a dose responsive fashion, and further whether the dose response is linear or whether it just gets weird at the higher concentrations.

As for the expected response, you will see in published work that sucrose or other sugars tend to encourage, rather than inhibit, root growth in most plants. Here for example is [Figure 4 from a paper](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1203746109):

[image]

The left panel has no sucrose added and the right panel has 30mM sucrose added. You can clearly see longer roots in the presence of sucrose, at least in these young *Arabidopsis* seedlings.

Comment: tl;dr is not standard English but internet slang. Please replace it.

Comment: @David it's common parlance everywhere in SE, which is in turn, in (or on) the internet. https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22tl%3bdr%22&searchOn=3

Comment: @uhoh — Correction it is a text/SMS abbreviation. The fact that computing and IT types on Stack Overflow may be inclined to use it has no relevance to SE Biology, which as a scientific site aims for clear, unambiguous and inclusive communication.

Comment: @David part of inclusiveness is tolerance - not insisting things be just the way you personally think they should be. We're all just individual users here. The community has embraced tl;dr, it's here to stay. Also, cf. [OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/tldr_int?tl=true) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/TL%3BDR)

Comment: @uhoh — Could we please refrain from personalizing this, either in suggesting that I am being intolerant and that I am trying to force my views on the site. “Biology Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for biology researchers, academics, and students”, with the aspiration of building a library that will be a valuable resource to its users. One of the ways SE attempts to achieve high standards is by allowing edits of both questions and answers, and it allows comments expressly to suggest improvements in answers. The latter is what I did. I also took the trouble to improve the question.

Comment: @uhoh (cont)The common language of the users of this SE is standard English, and using slang etc. that is only understood by a subsection of users is a barrier to those who do not understand it, deters serious scientists who might contribute, and results in the adoption of such undesirable terms by neophytes, to their future professional detriment. This holds whether such terms are textese, non-standard abbreviations or foreign phrases (of which I admit to having been guilty on occasions). The inclusiveness of language is part of SE policy. The embrace of niche slang is not.

Comment: @David "tl;dr" is perfectly fine in ALL Stack Exchange sites. There's no basis to go around suggesting here and there that people shouldn't use it. If you'd like to start a new site policy, go to meta and ask "Shall we ban tl;drs in Biology SE?" and see what the rest of the community thinks.

Comment: To get back to the topic - surely the problem with the higher concentrations is osmotic effects rather than an inhibition of growth as such.

Comment: @uhoh wrote “tl;dr is perfectly fine”… …except that it is unnecessarily incomprehensible to a section of native English-speaking qualified biologists. I have not sought to **ban** anything, nor would it be within the remit of this site to do so. If I migrated this topic to Meta it would not be to micromanage people’s vocabulary, but to explain my view of *the practical implications of the principles already adopted by SE* to help them implement them theirselves. I have already made myself clear in this particular case, and SE Biology will not disintegrate if the poster chooses to persist.

Comment: @bob1 that's a good point. I'll add something.